# Extract URL's directory from path, without file name such as "index.html"

Tags: javascript

I am looking for plain JavaScript code (no jQuery etc.) to learn the directory path component of my currently loaded page's URL.

For instance, if my page is loaded as "http://localhost/myapp/index.html", I like to end up with "http://localhost/myapp/".

I need this in order to create the path to a different file in the same location, e.g. to "http://localhost/myapp/other.html".

Comment: Are you sure you can't just rely on a relative path? A link to "other.html" will point at the same directory that "index.html" is in.

Comment: I need the absolute path, though, because I need to pass it to the server as a redirection URL (for the Dropbox API, actually)

Comment: The simple solution is `location.href.replace(/[^/]*$/, '');` then.

Comment: See the [location API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location) and do `console.log(location);`

Comment: Ah, thanks. I wonder if I should delete this question again, as it seems to be rather simple. I'm just a beginner with JS, still.

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily delete it. If it's helpful for you, it's bound to be useful for someone else.

Comment: You may also find [URL.js](http://medialize.github.io/URI.js/) useful, depending on your need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get the current "directory", we actually need to check if we're dealing with a URL that ends in "a file-like name" (e.g. `index.html` or `page.php` etc.) or not, because we can't just cut off "everything after the last `/`". If we did, we'd end up turning things like `example.com/faq` into `example.com`, for instance. And, we also need to take into account that the URL might end in a bunch of query arguments, a fragment identifier, or both. So it's a little bit more work then you'd initially think, but not a *lot* more work:

```js
// Let's hardcode a url
const fakeLocation = {
  href: `https://example.com/faq/questions.html?t=655423761#main`
};

let path = fakeLocation.href;
console.log(`looking at URL: ${path}`);

// Is this a file-like path, e.g. http.../foo.bar?
const regex = /^(.*)\/([^.]+(\.([^\/?#]+))+)(\?[^#]*)?(#.*)?$/;
const match = path.match(regex);

// Only if it is, do we cut that part off:
if (match !== null) {
  const { [1]:dirname, [2]:file, [4]:ext } = match;
  console.log(
    `URL is for a file "${file}", with extension "${ext}"`
  );
  path = dirname;
}

console.log(`just the "dir" part is: ${path}`);
```

In this, the regex breaks down as:

```
^              - the start of the string
(              - start of the first capture group
  .*           - as much as we can possibly match while still matching the rest
)              - end of the first capture group
\/             - a slash
(              - start of the second capture group
  [^.]+        - anything that isn't a dot
  (            - start of the third capture group
    \.         - a dot
    (          - the start of the fourth capture group
      [^\/?#]+ - anything that isn't a /, ?, or #
    )+         - the end of the fourth capture group, there can be 1 or more.
  )            - start of the third capture group
)              - the end of the second capture group
(              - the start of the fifth capture group
  \?           - a question mark
  [^#]+        - anything that isn't a #
)?             - the end of the fifth capture group, marked as optional
(              - the start of the sixth capture group
  #            - a hash/pound sign
  .+           - as much as we can possibly match while still matching the rest
)?             - the end of the sixth capture group, marked as optional
$              - the end of the string
```

This will find a "file-like" URL even if it's followed by a URL query, hash, or both, and will let you do something with them (because sometimes you need them, sometimes you don't), as well as explicitly capturing the full "file name" and "extension". So if we have a URL like `https://example.com/faq/questions.html?t=655423761#main`, this regex will capture:

```js
match = [​
  "https://example.com/faq/questions.html?t=655423761#main",
  "https://example.com/faq",
  ​"questions.html",
  ​".html",
  ​"html",
  ​"?t=655423761",
  ​"#main",
]
```

"Why are we capturing `html` *and* `.html`?" because your "filename" might be something like `questions.main.html`: just like real file names, there could be arbitrary many `.blah` parts, so we want to capture all of those. If our URL is `https://example.com/faq/questions.main.html?t=17862538#footer`, for instance, now the match will be:

```js
match = [​
  "https://example.com/faq/questions.main.html?t=17862538#footer"
​  "https://example.com/faq"
  ​"questions.main.html"
  ​".main.html"
  ​"main.html"
  ​"?t=17862538"
​  "#footer"
]
```

And of course, if we don't have a filename-like ending to our URL, like in `https://example.com/faq/questionshtml?t=655423761#main` (note the missing `.` between `question` and `html`) then `match` will just be `null`.

Answer (score 21):

It looks like this does the trick:

```
var href = window.location.href;
var dir = href.substring(0, href.lastIndexOf('/')) + "/";
```

Is this a safe method or can this fail with more complex URLs?

Comment: I wonder, though, if URLs even allow "/" to be used in the query part (after "?"). Won't they have to be encoded then?

Comment: what about `localhost/client/build` ? It becomes `localhost/client` which might be not what you want

Answer (score 3):

One more option to consider, which has the benefit that any query string will not be an issue since window.location.pathname does not pick up the query string.

```
window.location.origin + window.location.pathname.slice(0, window.location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Highlighting the comment in the question that helped me:

[Phylogenesis's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30863164/extract-urls-directory-from-path-without-file-name-such-as-index-html#comment49768740_30863164):

> The simple solution is location.href.replace(/[^/]*$/, ''); then.

Comment: For those who wonder what this does: It finds all after the last slash, and deletes that, so that only the text before and including the last "/" remains.

Answer (score 0):

A better solution would be

```
location.href.replace(/\/[^\/]+?\.[^\/]+?$/, '/')
```

Comment: You should add explanation of what your code will do.

Comment: When testing this (see here: https://regex101.com/r/X20kAO/1/ ), it does something else than what was asked for: It turns "http://localhost/myapp/index.html" into "http:/", it seems.

Comment: Yeah sorry, the updated version should work

Comment: note this ignores the possibility of query arguments or a fragment identifier after the "filename".